# Powershell issue with variable value 0

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a PS script that will a database and perform an action if the variable returned is not 0.
I have tried in many ways, but it doesn't work. It works for other values than 0.

Here is my script, using PS 3.0:

```
Import-Module .\Invoke-SqlCmd2.psm1

$server=servername
$database=databasename
$query="SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TABLE WHERE LogDateTime between Dateadd(MI, -15, getdate()) and getdate()"

$errors=(Invoke-SqlCmd2 -Serverinstance $server -Database $database -query $query).ItemArray
If ((get-variable -name errors -valueonly) -eq 0) {Write-Host "All Good!"} else {send alert email}
```

It acts like the variable is not 0 and performs the alert email part, even though the variable is actually 0:

```
PS C:\PSScripts> get-variable errors -valueonly

0
```

Has anyone ran into this before? If so, what's the fix for this?
Note I also tried this:
If

```
($errors.value -eq 0)
```

Also tried with -le 1 and everything, doesn't seem to believe the variable value is actually 0.

Comment: can you post the Invoke-SqlCmd2 code?

Comment: Guessing that it is 0 the string and not zero the integer or something else related to the type of `$errors`

Comment: The code to the invoke-sqlcmd2 is here:

Comment: The code to invoke-sqlcmd2 http://poshcode.org/4967. I cannot use the original one as I cant install ssms or the tools on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these scenarios where the unexpected is happening what happens when you check the type of your variable?

```
$errors.GetType().FullName
```

If it says anything but integer you might be having an issue. I do not know what else can be potentially returned but you might just be able to do a cast or something similar.

```
If([int]$errors -eq 0){"Stuff"}Else{"Send Email"}
```

**Update from comments**

We are on the right track. It's a type issue. So your function is returning an array. Assuming that you cannot change the function we would have to deal with the output but I'm not sure what is the best approach since I don't have an example to play with..... Perhaps we check the first element of the array returned.

```
If([int]$errors[0] -eq 0){"Stuff"}Else{"Send Email"}
```

In the mean time I am going to check the link to the code you posted.

Comment: The variable appears to be a System.Object[]. I tried with the cast suggested but I can't change it: PS C:\PSScripts> If ([int]$errors -eq 0) {Write-Host "GOOD!"}
Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type
"System.Int32".
At line:1 char:5
+ If ([int]$errors -eq 0) {Write-Host "Everything is Awesome!"}
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException

Comment: I don't think it can be cast as int :[bool]($errors -as [int] -is [int])
False

Comment: @kan3xxx Good work. Check my updated. I have some reading to to in the meantime. Since its an array we need to deal with that.

Comment: Thank you, the [0] works now, with that cast it actually agrees that the variable is 0.